# Eclipse: Ctrl+Shift+Right is incorrect

Tags: java, eclipse, key-bindings

Consider this simple class:

```
package net.zomis.test;

public class Test {
    public Test() {

    }

    public void registerSomething(String key) {

    }

}
```

When I have the cursor placed right before `registerSomething` and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>, I'm used to Eclipse only selecting `register` at first. But now, it selects the entire `registerSomething` text, when I press it again it selects the entire method (from `public void` to `}`), when I press it again it selects the entire class, and the last time the entire file is selected. The exactly same thing happens if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>.

Also, when I simply click the <kbd>End</kbd> key, I get an option to choose: *Line End* or *Text End*.

What has gone wrong in my settings for this to happen? Where can I find these keybindings?

If it matters, I have this workspace within my Dropbox-folder to synchronize it between my PC and Mac.

Comment: The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33374783/4398851) solved it for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns our that the fact that I had the workspace in my Dropbox folder matters **a lot**. Note to everybody else: **Do not share your workspace between computers**. How I solved this is the following:

- Create a new workspace on each computer
- In the computer-specific workspace, import projects from your shared Dropbox/other folder

I noticed that when having a shared workspace on the computers, the Mac somehow changed the key-bindings to the Mac-version, which made them not work on the PC. The correct <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> key-binding on Mac is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>.

So by using a separate workspace on each computer, I can use that computer's specific key-bindings, without mixing them up.

Answer (score 5):

Open the preferences dialog from the Main Menu: *Window->Preferences*.

In the dialog, open *General->Keys*. You'll see a table of keybindings, with a field with *type filter text*. In that field, type: `Ctrl+Shift+Right`, and you'll narrow the table down to this key.

The behavior that you expect - only `register` is selected with the first keypress - is the behavior that I see when using *Ctrl+Shift+Right*, and the keybinding for me is: *Select Next Word*.

There is a *Restore Command* button that should reset this binding if it has been changed.

Comment: Many thanks for this, it turns out that my key-bindings was screwed up by sharing the workspace with the Mac, see my answer below. Your answer helped me find the correct key-binding for Mac!